# i have token in header of ajax and when i get dd return null

Tags: ajax, laravel, cookies, header, token

i wanna send GET request from frontend to backend
i mean i want to send token from frontend to middlware
i mean i want get token from cookie and push in GET request and send for one of route in api.php that the route is GET method
i mean i want to push my token in ajax and send to laravel
infact i have two laravel project that i want send token from one to another
i mean i want push my token in header in ajax and get in backend with laravel
so see my code in the below fisrt my route from backend
later my jquery and then middleware

but my current problem is that when i dd header is is null
thanks

```
Route::get('/customers', 'App\Http\Controllers\CustomerController@show');
```

//

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:8000/api/customers",
    type: "GET",
    headers: {
        "Authorization": getCookie("access_token")
    }
});
```

//

```
dd($request->header('Authorization'));

if ($request->hasHeader('Authorization')) {

    $access_token = $request->header('Authorization');
    $query = DB::table("admins")->where("access_token", $access_token)->first();

    if (isset($access_token) && $access_token == $query->access_token) {
        return $next($request);
    } else {
        return response()->json([
            "status" => 401,
            "message" => "شما اجازه دسترسی ندارید",
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: So lets get this edited to You have two laravel projects (project 1 and project 2) and you want to send ajax request from project 1 to hit endopoint in project 2 and transfer token from project 1 to project 2 , right ? And also when you do the dd on project 2 you don't see token, ( do you see it in ajax call ?)

Comment: sometimes the server needs to be setup to accept token headers.  Are you on nginx?

Comment: yes exactly. in the back-end when i get dd($request->header('Authorization')); the result is null. and in ajax call in the success method i put alert(getCookie("access_token")); and it works and it get print. i mean in the front-end it`s okay but in back-end it`s not @JozefBarca

Comment: no i`m in local @Cameron

Comment: what if you dd $request->header();  to see all headers?

Comment: local like php artisan serve?   valet?  sail/docker?  or local by flywheel for wordpresS?

Comment: What I'm trying to say is:  if you are serving via apache, you need to add the handle for Authorization headers seen here: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/public/.htaccess    . If you are on NGINX you also need to do the same in the config.  https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/deployment#nginx  If you are on PHP artisan serve, I'm not sure you can modify those things, if you are in sail then it should be done and there is a different issue.